# How to "inject" partialView elements into DOM to add jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a partialView:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Trip Id</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th>Actual Distance</th>
            <th>Air Distance</th>
            <th>Avg Speed</th>
            <th>Max Speed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="trip" data-id="@item.TripId" data-url="@Url.Action("","")">
                <td>@item.TripId</td>
                <td>@item.StartTimeStamp</td>
                <td>@item.EndTimeStamp</td>
                <td>@item.ActualDistance</td>
                <td>@item.AirDistance</td>
                <td>@item.AvgSpeed</td>
                <td>@item.MaxSpeed</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

that is loaded through a jQuery `.load()` function. However I have found that when it is loaded like this inside my site.js file the `.trip` class is not added to the DOM before the load and therefore I can't write any code that reacts to:

```
$(".trip").click()
```

How can I fix this issue?

NB: I have all my Javascript/jQuery code inside my `site.js`
[image]

## Edit

Snippet for loading the partialView:

```
$("#TripPartial").slideUp('200', function () {
    $('#TripPartial').load(_this.data('url'), { id: _this.data('id') }, function () {
        $("#TripPartial").slideDown('200');
    });
});
```

Comment: can you add js code where you call the load() function

Comment: @VolkanSeçkinAkbayır Sure. I will be getting right to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `event delegation` for elements which were added dynamically.

You should bind `click` event handler using `.on()` method.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

```
$(document).on('click','.trip',function(){

});
```

Comment: After having tested it a little it seems that I need to "double"-click for the event to fire. Is there a solution to this or is it just the rest of my code that is sluggish?

Comment: Nvm. I found the problem. I had a ".click" event inside my "click" event ;)